# TypeErrors with Yoast, jQuery in conflict?

Tags: plugins, jquery, javascript, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

The update to version 4.7 of Yoast have created a big problem.

It not works and I can't "Rolleback" for prior versions.
Only until to version 2.3.5 works.

Here the errors in the browser console:
[image]

It looks like a jQuery conflict. In the page with the errors (wp-admin/post.php) are loaded jQuery 1.12.4 and jQuery 1.11.3

[image]

Suggestions?

Comment: Why is your page loading two versions of jQuery? You should only enqueue the WordPress included version of jQuery.

Comment: I have attached a pic with the 2 versions loaded. Before of the update to version 4.7, the version 4.6 was perfect. This can be the cause of the conflict?

Comment: You're loading all of the admin scripts on the front end? Or is this an admin screen?

Comment: I haven't changed nothing in the loading of the scripts. Only update to new version of Yoast. Maybe this update have registered a new version of jQuery? The screen of the conflict is the page wp-admin/post.php

Comment: This seems like a question for Yoast support.

Answer (score 0):

**bbPress caused a jQuery Conflict**. I have delete it, also because I haven't install it.

Verified the options on **phpMyAdmin database**.

**Empty all caches** with **W3 Total Cache**.

Now works all again.